# Load Google ReCaptcha Without Composer

Tags: php, include, composer-php, recaptcha

PHP libraries usually provide installation instructions on how to include their resources without relying on Composer. However, [this Google ReCaptcha library](https://github.com/google/recaptcha) only has installation instructions for using Composer, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I might include the library using a more traditional include method.

Could someone please explain how I might go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the issue of why you don't want to use composer, I see two options for you:

First clone the repository into your project and delete the version control information. (Alternatively you could use a git submodule or subtree).

```
cd myProject
git clone https://github.com/google/recaptcha.git
cd recaptcha
rm -rf .git
```

1. **Require each file** individually

   ```
   $recaptchaBase = '/path/to/myProject/recaptcha/src';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/ReCaptcha.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/RequestMethod.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/RequestParameters.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/Response.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/RequestMethod/Post.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/RequestMethod/Socket.php';
   require_once $recaptchaBase . '/RequestMethod/SocketPost.php';
   ```
2. **Build the composer autoloader** for the library then just include that.

   First build the autoloader:

   ```
   cd '/path/to/myProject/recaptcha'
   composer install
   ```

   Then include that from your script:

   ```
   require_once '/path/to/myProject/recaptcha/vendor/autoload.php';
   ```

In method 2 you still need composer to build the autoloader initially, but you don't need to rely on it for your whole app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try requiring them each individually. I haven't yet wrapped by head around how Composer works, and sometimes the server doesn't have composer installed or I don't have shell access to install it.